# Relaxing type checking when using 'with type' construction in modules

Tags: module, types, ocaml, signature

I have defined two module types and two modules

```
module type FOO = sig type e end
module type BAR = sig type t end    
module Foo : FOO = struct type e = int end
module Bar : BAR = struct type t = int end
```

Then I define a functor as

```
module Fun (F:FOO) (B:BAR with type t = F.e) = struct type x = string end
```

(this is a toy example, please ignore the fact that `F` and `B` are not used by the functor)

Now, if I define the module

```
module Bla = Fun (Foo) (Bar)
```

I get

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match:
         sig type t = Bar.t end
       is not included in
         sig type t = Foo.e end
       Type declarations do not match:
         type t = Bar.t
       is not included in
         type t = Foo.e
```

Although both `Bar.t` and `Foo.e` are defined as `int` OCaml considers `Bar.t` and `Foo.e` to be different. That's just the way the typing system works and it makes sense to consider these two types different in general (c.f. last paragraph of [Functors and Type Abstraction](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html#toc16)).

**Question**: *Sometimes* I may want this to pass type checking because for my purposes they can be considered equal. Is there a way to relax this?

---

Using gasche's suggestion of removing coercion, the above code can be written as

```
module type FOO = sig type e end
module type BAR = sig type t end
module Foo = struct type e = int end
module Bar = struct type t = int end
module Fun (F : FOO with type e=int) (B : BAR with type t = int) = struct type x = F.e * B.t end
module Bla = Fun (Foo) (Bar)
```

which compiles fine. Strangely, I get

```
# let f x : Bla.x = (x,x);;
val f : Foo.e -> Bla.x = <fun>
```

**Question**: why does it infer that `x` is `Foo.e`? It could as well be `Bar.t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is how you define `Foo` and `Bar` : `module Foo : FOO = ...`. By imposing this signature here, you "seal" the module and make the type abstract. It cannot be reverted. You should remove the `: FOO` coercion here, and use it later when you need the abstraction. You could also use `module Foo : (FOO with type e = int) = ...`.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'll leave coercions to as late as possible. There's something about doing it that doesn't sound good, but the code I have (of which the above is a toy example) is now working, so I'll live with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the printer chooses amongst equal types, but in this case you can cause it to print a different name by explicitly annotating your function argument:

```
# let f (x:Bar.t) : Bla.x = (x,x);;
val f : Bar.t -> Bla.x = <fun>
```